# Error using next in for loop - no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

Tags: r, for-loop

I keep getting this error in my For loop:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

```
autoAnal <- function(x){  
    if(!is.numeric(x)){  
        next  
    }  
    m <- median(x, na.rm = T)  
    a <- mean(x, na.rm = T)  
    s <- sd(x, na.rm = T)  
    q <- quantile(x, na.rm = T)  
    q3 <- q[4]  
    q1 <- q[2]  
    outhigh <- (1.5 * q3) + IQR(x, na.rm = T)  
    outlow <- (1.5 * q1) - IQR(x, na.rm = T)    
    data.table(Median = m, Average = a, StDev = s,   
    Outhigh = outhigh, Outlow = outlow)  
}
```

Channel Data
Channel  june  july  december
ATM  666  783  333
VISA  893 321  321
DEBIT 931  134  123
MERCHANT  913  111  134

The first varible - "Channel" is not numerical, so I want R to skip and go to the next variable. However, I get the error above. I can run the function successfully on a numerical vector, but when I use a dataframe or data.table
it doesn't work.
When I run this code I get the error:

```
test <- lapply(channnel, autoAnal)
```

What am I doing wrong with the 'next' statement in my for loop?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no `for` loop in your code. At least not where you think there is. Replace `next` with `return(NULL)` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @brittenb could you explain why the next function isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand why `next` doesn't work, we have to break down the two parts of your code that you've attempted. To do this, it makes more sense to work backwards and examine how `lapply` works. Let's start with a basic variable called `i` and set it equal to the numbers 1 through 10. Once we have that, we'll use `lapply` to see how the function handles an input vector.

```
i <- 1:10
tmp <- lapply(i, as.character)
```

If you run that code and look at `tmp`, you'll see that we get a list with 10 elements, where each element in the list is a single number stored as a string. What this should show you is that `lapply` works as a loop going through each element of an object that you've passed to it and feeding that into whatever function you've chosen. So let's use that to look at what your code is doing.

```
test <- lapply(channnel, autoAnal)
```

This is going to take the first element of `channnel` and pass it into your function `autoAnal`. At this point, the code switches from the loop that `lapply` is running and steps into a single function call. The first thing your function does is checks if the element that has been passed into the function is numeric or not. If it's not, you use `next` to tell R to skip that variable.

However, `next` only works in loops, such as `while` and `for`. So let's go back to our `i` variable. Let's say we wanted to loop over `i` and print a message if the number is even, otherwise, skip to the next number. We can do that like this:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  if (i %% 2 == 0) {
    print("i is even!")
  } else {
    next
  }
}
```

In this instance, using `next` doesn't throw an error because it's used within a `for` loop. That's why in my comment I mentioned that there is no `for` loop, at least not where you think there is. My intention behind saying this was to point out that, yes, `lapply` is a loop, but not for the sake of what you're trying to do with `next`.

So, what if we just tried to use next with an `if` statement?

```
i <- 5
if (i %% 2 == 0) {
  print("i is even")
} else {
  next
}
```

This will throw an error because your code isn't a loop. There's just one interation that it's going to go through, which involves checking if `i` is even or not, and then moving on. Much in the same way that `next` doesn't work here, it's not working in your code because the `if` statement is just checking if the element passed to it is numeric. There's nothing for it to "next" to if that makes sense. For this reason, `next` is only used with loops.

In my opinion, `next` is never even really needed. You can always just use `if/else` statements to run code if needed or otherwise just ignore the variable. As an example, let's rewrite your code to take advantage of `if/else` and get rid of our `next` call.

```
autoAnal <- function(x){  
  if(is.numeric(x)){  
    m <- median(x, na.rm = T)  
    a <- mean(x, na.rm = T)  
    s <- sd(x, na.rm = T)  
    q <- quantile(x, na.rm = T)  
    q3 <- q[4]  
    q1 <- q[2]  
    outhigh <- (1.5 * q3) + IQR(x, na.rm = T)  
    outlow <- (1.5 * q1) - IQR(x, na.rm = T)    
    data.table(Median = m, Average = a, StDev = s,   
    Outhigh = outhigh, Outlow = outlow)
  } else {
    print("Skipping this element")
  }
}
```

By using `if/else`, we tell the computer to only perform those calculations on variables if they're numeric. Otherwise, print a message saying we're skipping a variable. In normal code, I'd advise just dropping the `else` statement all together. `lapply` will naturally return `NULL` if there is no value returned, and the function will skip all of the code completely for the first variable since it's not numeric. In the end, you end up with an error-free function that only operates on numeric data.

Hopefully that helps illustrate why `next` doesn't work in your current context.